# Auto-create bookmark by number of pages listed in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, javascript, bookmarks, adobe-acrobat

I have a 2,000ish page PDF that I need to split into about 400 smaller PDFs each with various numbers of pages. I'm tracking the number of pages for each split, and the beginning page number and last page number from the main large PDF for each individual document (the split locations). Is there a way to use that spreadsheet to auto generate the bookmarks and split? I don't need bookmark names, but if I could use a field from the spreadsheet, that would be nice too. Thanks!

Comment: Excel does have Pagination on Header & Footer and while split Sheets to PDF you can use VBA controls splitting certain pages or series of pages.

Comment: What tool are you using to split the pdf file? If the tool accepts command line parameters then you could create a VBA script that would take your parameters from your spreadsheet and run the command line with those parameters.

Comment: @gns100, I'm using the split by top level bookmark in Acrobat. I was hoping for some javascript that I could customize using the excel data. I ended up using a free trial of a paid plugin that did exactly what I needed in no time. It would still be interesting to figure out a javascript workaround for when that expires.